# installing sitecake

Tags: php, config

I am trying to use sitecake www.sitecake.com on my website. I installed it using the instructions here http://sitecake.com/install.html and tested it on the about page.

The PHP is misbehaving, and unfortunately I an at a loss on what the problem is. I've searched for the different PHP errors for a couple days now and came up with one solution for part of the problem, but I still can't get it to work correctly.

After I installed sitecake and added the line  to the top of the about page, I got this error when I tried to access the page:

PHP Error Message

PHP Code:

> Warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in 
>   effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs) is not within the allowed 
>   path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in 
>   /home/a5940384/public_html/sitecake/server/config.php on line 12

PHP Error Message

PHP Code:

> Warning: substr_compare() [function.substr-compare]: The length must
>   be greater than zero in
>   /home/a5940384/public_html/sitecake/server/config.php on line 14

An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

PHP Code:

```
Message: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir
restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs//about.php) is
not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp)  Stack trace: 
#0 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/PageTemplateImpl.php(30): Bootstrap::globalErrorHandler(2, 'file_exists() [...', '/home/a3779563/...', 30, Array)
#1 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/RenderServiceImpl.php(54): PageTemplateImpl->setPageRequest('/usr/local/apac...')
#2 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/RenderServiceImpl.php(23): RenderServiceImpl->renderResponse('/index.php')
#3 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/application/controllers/RenderController.php(13): RenderServiceImpl->render()
#4 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): RenderController->renderAction('/index.php', false)
#5 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch()
#6 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch('renderAction')
#7 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#8 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#9 /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/sitecake_entry.php(47): Zend_Application->run()
#10 /home/a3779563/public_html/index.php(1): include('/home/a3779563/...')
#11 {main}
```

Request Parameters:

> array (    'controller' => 'render',    'action' => 'render',  )

I was able to fix these errors by replacing

PHP Code:

```
$doc_root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

on lines 12 and 23

with

PHP Code:

```
$doc_root = dirname(_FILE_);
```

in sitecake/server/config.php (found that fix on the forum while searching for open_basedir restrictions)

Here's the whole config.php script in question  after the change:
PHP Code:

```
 <?php  
define( 'CONTENT_DIR', dirname(dirname(SITECAKE_SERVER_BASE_DIR)).DS.'sitecake-content'); 
define( 'APP_TMP_DIR', CONTENT_DIR.DS.'temp' ); 

define('LICENSE_PATH', dirname(SITECAKE_SERVER_BASE_DIR).DS.'license.key'); 
define( 'CREDENTIAL_FILE', SITECAKE_SERVER_BASE_DIR.DS.'credential.php' ); 
define( 'SITECAKE_EDITOR_CONFIG_FILE', dirname(SITECAKE_SERVER_BASE_DIR).DS.'editor.cfg' ); 

# define( 'SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL', '/' ); 
if ( !defined('SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL') ) 
{ 
    $doc_root = dirname(_FILE_);  
    $entryDir = realpath(dirname(dirname(SITECAKE_SERVER_BASE_DIR))); 
    if ( substr_compare($entryDir, $docRootDir, 0, strlen($docRootDir)) != 0 ) die('Unable to determine SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL'); 
    define( 'SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL', str_replace('\\', '/', substr($entryDir, strlen($docRootDir)))); 
} 

define( 'SERVICE_URL', SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL.'/sitecake/server/sitecake_entry.php' ); 
define( 'SITECAKE_PUBLIC_MANAGER_URL', SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL.'/sitecake/client/publicmanager/publicmanager.nocache.js' ); 
define( 'SITECAKE_CONTENT_MANAGER_URL', SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL.'/sitecake/client/contentmanager/contentmanager.nocache.js' ); 
define( 'CONTENT_BASE_URL', SITECAKE_BASE_RELATIVE_URL.'/sitecake-content'); 

define( '$doc_root = dirname(_FILE_);'] ); 

define( 'PHP_TEMPLATE', false ); 
define( 'TEMPLATE_CACHING', true ); 

$applicationIncludes = array( 
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH), 
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.DS.'controllers'), 
    realpath(APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PATH), 
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.DS.'services'.DS.'impl'.DS.'onesite'), 
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.DS.'services'.DS.'impl'.DS.'basic'), 
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.DS.'services'), 
    get_include_path(), 
); 

?>
```

and was able to access the site, but when I try to log in to sitecake I get this error in the log in box:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/config.php on line 23
```

I can' find anything for PHP errors that is helpful, so now I'm at a loss.

Any ideas on how to use site cake with 000webhost?

If you made it this far thanks for reading!

the URL for the site: http://nave.net23.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'd just turn off [base_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) for starters if you can.  Note, disabling safe_mode would not prevent the base_dir stuff.

As for the error you are getting now its simply telling you that there is a syntax error.  Now I am not seeing it in what you posted.  Maybe you fixed it locally but not on server yet?

Comment: you can see the error in this URL:  http://nave.net23.net/ 
and i do not really understand what should i do...

Comment: I'd back out your changes and start by turning off base_dir.  Hopefully you are  able to do that even with shared hosting.  See [instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir).  Then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have PHP safe mode in place on that server (which looks like it might be some shared host server by the looks of your `/home/a5940384/public_html` directory structure,

For whatever reason that app wants to look for files in `/usr/local/apache/htdocs`. So you probably will need to look through all the code to find out why it thinks that is your base directory.  Maybe find out where `SITECAKE_SERVER_BASE_DIR` is defined as this seems to be the main constant used for calculating file paths.

Shared hosting is the devil's business.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it is very hurd for me to do it, I do not really understand PHP and certainly not at the level of  change its code
what should i do?

Comment: @NaveTseva Search the codebase for `SITECAKE_SERVER_BASE_DIR` and figure out what value is being set for that.

Comment: How do you search for any portion of code that you want to find in a codebase you are using?  It depends on the OS and development tools you are using. Or if you have command line access on the server, just `grep` for it.

Comment: ok i did it and now there is only 1 error, how can i fix it?
 http://nave.net23.net/

Comment: this is the error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/config.php on line 23
 
i replace this '$doc_root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];' in this 
$doc_root = dirname(_FILE_);
in lines 12 and 23

Comment: I assume this is line 23: `define( '$doc_root = dirname(_FILE_);'] ); `  This would certainly throw an error, but I can't tell what this is trying to do, perhaps you did a find replace that went wrong here? What did this line show before?

Comment: befor the change this was the error 
Warning: substr_compare() [function.substr-compare]: The length must be greater than zero

Comment: @NaveTseva What was the actual line of code before the change?

Comment: Warning: substr_compare() [function.substr-compare]: The length must be greater than zero in /home/a3779563/public_html/sitecake/server/config.php on line 23

Comment: @NaveTseva That is not a line of code, that is an error message. What was the actual code on line 23 that was replaced by `define( '$doc_root = dirname(_FILE_);'] );`?

Comment: define( 'DOCUMENT_ROOT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );